# How to make a div appear on top of another while keeping size?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navbar menu similar to [airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com). I'm stuck with the dropdown menu. How could I make it so that it stays on top of main?

Here's my html:

```
<div>
    <div class="header__loginMenu">
        <img src="./img/bars-solid.svg" alt="menu">
        <img src="./img/user-solid.svg" alt="usuario">
    </div>

    <div class="header__userMenu">
        <a href="register.html">Registrate</a>
        <a href="login.html">Iniciar sesión</a>
        <a href="#">Cerrar sesión</a>
        <a href="cart.html">Carrito</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```
.header__loginMenu {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.header__loginMenu:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 8px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__loginMenu > *:first-child {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}

.header__loginMenu img {
  height: 1.5rem;
}

.header__userMenu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.08), 0 4px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  padding: 1rem;
}

.header__userMenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Also, I made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/dexternaru/pen/XWPYKjw)

Answer (score 0):

Set your header css to be sticky to the top:

```
.header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

You might also want to give your header a fixed height rather than a max-height.

A working example: https://dev.to/akhilarjun/one-line-sticky-header-using-css-5gp3